# Making a rectangle made out of a given set of rectangles sizes (get the size as closest as the given one)

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I'm actually working on a ruby project and need some help.
I have these inputs :

- **sizeX** and **sizeY** as an integer
- **rectangles**, which is an array of arrays containing two integers.

I’ll take these values as example :

- **sizeX** = 130
- **sizeY** = 240
- **rectangles** = **[** [100,100], [100,150], [50,100], [50,50] **]**

---

With the input i have, i need an algorithm that creates a new rectangle, made of the sizes given in **rectangles**, that will make a resulting size as closest as **sizeX** and **sizeY**. I’m gonna call the created rectangle size **rectX** and **rectY**.
This closest determination will be calculated like so :

`abs(sizeX - rectX) + abs(sizeY - rectY)`
*So it returns the smallest total difference*

Here are some rules of what the algorithm can and can’t do :

- We can use multiple times the same rectangle
- We can’t rotate a rectangle (In the case of the example, we can’t have 150x100)
- We have to use the least rectangles possible

---

Here is an illustrated example of a result :

[image: Illustration 1]

Here is another example if the rectangle [50,100] is not given in **rectangles** :

[image: Illustration 2]

---

I have done some code, but it's not efficient, and is a pretty big mess :

```rb
# Returns the biggest cabinet from a given list
  def getBiggestCabinet(cabinets)
    cabinets.sort_by!{ |rect| rect.cabinetsize_w * rect.cabinetsize_h }.reverse!
    return cabinets.first
  end

  # Returns number of cabinets that fits inside a given width & height + its gap
  def getCabinetClosestMatch(width,height,cabinet)
    countX = (width / cabinet.cabinetsize_w).floor
    countY = (height / cabinet.cabinetsize_h).floor
    gapX = width - countX * cabinet.cabinetsize_w
    gapY = height - countY * cabinet.cabinetsize_h
    return countX, countY, gapX, gapY
  end

  # Only takes on cabinet at a time
  def getBestCabinetByLength(cabinets,gap,match,x_or_y)
    sorted = cabinets.sort_by!{ |cabinet|
      if x_or_y
        return cabinet.cabinetsize_w - gap
      else
        return cabinet.cabinetsize_h - gap
      end
    }

    bestLength = 0
    sorted.each do |cabinet|
      if x_or_y
        if match.modulo(cabinet.cabinetsize_h) == 0
          bestLength = cabinet.cabinetsize_h
          break;
        end
      else
        if match.modulo(cabinet.cabinetsize_w) == 0
          bestLength = cabinet.cabinetsize_w
          break;
        end
      end
    end

    return bestLength

  end

  def createCompatibleArrays(cabinets)
    # group cabinets by width or height
    cabinets_x = cabinets.group_by{ |c| c.caninetsize_w }.values
    cabinets_y = cabinets.group_by{ |c| c.caninetsize_h }.values

    return cabinets_x, cabinets_y
  end

  def getCabinetConfig(cabinets,width,height)

    biggestCabinet = getBiggestCabinet(cabinets)
    countX, countY, gapX, gapY = getCabinetClosestMatch(width,height,biggestCabinet)

    current_width = width - gapX
    current_height = height - gapY

    cabinets = cabinets.where.not(id: biggestCabinet.id)

    cabinets_gx, cabinets_gy = createCompatibleArrays(cabinets)

    cabinets_gx.each do |c|
      unless c[0].cabinetsize_h / 2 > gapY
        
      end
    end

  end
```

Comment: The task definitions is not 100% clear now - it is not defined what does "close" mean. For example, in fig. A the rectangle could be 250x100 instead of 250x150 - taking into account 125 as a target width I don't really understand why the latter is closer than the former (_especially taking into account your additional criteria_ - "The idea is also to have the least rectangles used")

Comment: Hey ! Here are some clarifications :
- By closest, i mean that the difference between my input (width & height) and my created rectangle have to be the lowest possible (with the constraint of having a defined set of rectangle sizes).
- For the width of 125, you are right (my bad), i changed to 130 so it's logical

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for the tips ! I'll edit the question tomorrow to make everything clearer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I modified the whole question, is it clearer like that ?

Comment: Esteban, the question much clearer now. It appears, however, that you still have multiple objectives: `minimize abs(sizeX - rectX) + abs(sizeY - rectY)` and "We have to use the least rectangles possible". You can have only one objective.